# Firebase - Struct data

Tags: javascript, firebase

### The idea

I'm using Firebase has my back-end data storage and i have a list of users like this

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "member_number" : 1,
    "name": "b",
    "phone": "d",
    "email": "f",
    "picture" : "",
    "gender" : "male",
    "birthdate" : "21-05-1986",
    "address" : "",
    "postal_code" : {"prefix":"4750","suffix":"248"},
    "updated_on" : "1235648",
    "inserted_on" : "2014", 
    "visible" : true,
    "verified" : false
   }
```

and i have a list of year buckets like this, where the key is the bucket year

```
"buckets" : {
  "2014" : {},
  "2015" : {}
}
```

My goal is, when i insert a new user assign that user to the year bucket. So if i add a user in year 2014, that user go to the 2014 bucket, and if i add a user in 2015 that user go to the 2015 bucket and so on.

How i can do this with firebase? or how i can struct my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list of users, I would make ID the key. Then in each year bucket, I would just store a list of user ID's. So if you want to see a list of all users in 2014, you retrieve the list of user ID's, and then look up each user by ID.

To store a new user you might do something like:

```
var currentyear = "2015";

var newUser = {
    "id" : 1,
    "member_number" : 1,
    "name": "b",
    "phone": "d",
    "email": "f",
    "picture" : "",
    "gender" : "male",
    "birthdate" : "21-05-1986",
    "address" : "",
    "postal_code" : {"prefix":"4750","suffix":"248"},
    "updated_on" : "1235648",
    "inserted_on" : currentyear, 
    "visible" : true,
    "verified" : false
   };

var userList = new Firebase('https://foo.firebase.url//userList');
var userRef = userList.child(newUser.id);
userRef.set(newUser);

var bucketRef = new Firebase('https://foo.firebase.url//bucketList//' + currentyear);
bucketRef.push({"id": newUser.id});
```

In this way, it is easy to access and update a user's data, and to get a list of users by year.

Comment: This matches the recommended patterns in the docs. Great answer @Seamus!